# Statsmodels ACF Confidence Interval doesn't match - Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm trying find number of significant output using ACF graph, however results of statsmodels.tsa.acf() confidence intervals don't match with statsmodels.graphics.tsa.acf() graph.

Sample code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf,plot_pacf

acf,confidence_interval=sm.tsa.acf(df_data,nlags=df_data.shape[0]-1,alpha=0.05,fft=False)

plot_acf(df_data,lags=df_data.shape[0]-1)

print(confidence_interval)
```

Here is the plot,

[image: ACF Graph]

However, confidence interval values returned from sm.tsa.acf() is way different comparing to the values in the graph.

Returned Values;

```
[[ 1.          1.        ]
 [-0.27174973  0.37268246]
 [-0.3286431   0.31742828]
 [ 0.0203798   0.66647139]
 [-0.61221928  0.10569058]
 [-0.61407253  0.14003004]
 [-0.42569193  0.35873921]
 [-0.58610165  0.19892257]
 [-0.64565391  0.15895208]
 [-0.34123344  0.49337893]
 [-0.53223297  0.30525403]
 [-0.56775509  0.2760946 ]
 [-0.02246426  0.83178741]
 [-0.55237867  0.37808097]
 [-0.53964256  0.39420078]
 [-0.19144858  0.74474359]
 [-0.63752942  0.33201877]
 [-0.66170085  0.31779123]
 [-0.5026759   0.48927364]
 [-0.63266561  0.35930273]
 [-0.60042286  0.39933612]
 [-0.50945575  0.49449365]
 [-0.47942564  0.52454691]
 [-0.48578234  0.51840072]
 [-0.32312106  0.68117201]
 [-0.40066389  0.61679615]
 [-0.3917795   0.63043611]
 [-0.35304025  0.67494402]
 [-0.52974159  0.50865544]
 [-0.57667548  0.46176601]
 [-0.5657842   0.47397661]
 [-0.61493365  0.42566845]
 [-0.57909456  0.46507539]
 [-0.54230719  0.50315461]
 [-0.51974363  0.52587038]
 [-0.53350424  0.5121135 ]
 [-0.52597853  0.51968465]]
```

It seems like first value is matching the graph then, it becomes quite unrelated. I find similar question at [Statsmodels PACF plot confidence interval does not match PACF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855401/statsmodels-pacf-plot-confidence-interval-does-not-match-pacf-function) , yet there was no  solution. I read the documents, search through similar questions but I cannot find a solution.

How can I get the confidence interval values that are reflected on the graph?

Comment: duplicate, The answer in the linked question explains it. Just subtract the acf from the confidence interval to have it centered at zero.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

To get the confidence intervals that are reflected on the figure returned by `plot_acf`, you need to subtract the `acf_values` from the `confint` boundaries.

#### Example

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import acf

# Generate some sample time series data
np.random.seed(0)
t = np.linspace(0, 10, n)
time_series = np.sin(t)

# Calculate the ACF with confidence intervals using statsmodels
acf_values, confint = acf(time_series, alpha=0.05)

lower_bound = confint[1:, 0] - acf_values[1:]
upper_bound = confint[1:, 1] - acf_values[1:]

# Create lag values for the x-axis
lags = np.arange(0, len(acf_values))

# Plot the ACF with confidence intervals using Matplotlib
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.bar(lags, acf_values, width=0.2, align='center', label='ACF')

# Fill the area between upper and lower bounds
plt.fill_between(lags[1:], lower_bound, upper_bound, color='grey', alpha=0.2, label='95% Confidence Interval')

# Plot the upper and lower bounds
plt.plot(lags[1:], upper_bound, color='grey')
plt.plot(lags[1:], lower_bound, color='grey')

plt.axhline(y=0, color='black', linewidth=0.8, linestyle='dotted')
plt.xlabel('Lag')
plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
plt.title('Autocorrelation Function (ACF) with Confidence Interval')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Examplary ACF plot]

#### Explanation

`plot_acf` and `acf` differ in their intended use: `plot_acf` provides a quick visual representation of autocorrelation with a focus on visual interpretation, while `acf` is more geared towards providing the autocorrelation values themselves without the graphical context.

- `statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf` (with plotting) is primarily designed to plot the autocorrelation function (ACF) of a time series and provide visual insights. When calculating and plotting the ACF using `plot_acf`, the confidence interval is centered around zero. This is useful to visualize how the autocorrelation values deviate from the null hypothesis (no autocorrelation). See the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html#statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf-parameters) of `plot_acf`'s parameter `barlett_confint`.
- `statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.acf` (without plotting): The `acf` function is focused on calculating the autocorrelation function without creating a graphical plot. When you calculate the ACF using `acf`, the function doesn't center the confidence interval around zero but around the autocorrelation value itself. This can be useful for statistical calculations and hypothesis testing involving autocorrelation.

#### Reference

- [statsmodels documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html#)
- [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956425/11475733) on [Statsmodels PACF plot confidence interval does not match PACF function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855401/statsmodels-pacf-plot-confidence-interval-does-not-match-pacf-function).