Confidence interval given by acf and plot_acf in statsmodels are different
I have a large timeseries of around 1mil points. I am using statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf to compute the acf and the confidence intervals. Since I have a large dataset, the confidence intervals should be very small, and this is what plot_acf shows.
However, when I compute the confidence intervals through acf alone, it gives values much larger than what is plotted with plot_acf.
Is there a reason that the confidence intervals given by the two functions would be different?

How are they different? Is this duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210345/statsmodels-acf-confidence-interval-doesnt-match-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61855401/statsmodels-pacf-plot-confidence-interval-does-not-match-pacf-function
